# Unable to disable "mysql" service for autoboot

Tags: 14.04, services

I'm trying to disable a service:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d mysql disable
update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match mysql Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match mysql Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/mysql do not exist.
```

What does that mean? How can I disable it then?

Answer (score 8):

It means that the service in the `SysVInit` system is not enabled. The `mysql` is rather started through `upstart` in `/etc/init`.

To disable auto start of `mysql`.

```
echo "manual" > /etc/init/mysql.override
```

Comment: that file doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, correct. You have to create it.